# Неправильное отображение иконок шрифта при выполнении программы

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Привет всем. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. В моем приложении используется известный шрифт иконок fontawesome. Качнул с офф сайта. Закинул в проект. В ресурсах, где подключаю шрифты написал:
`<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">pack://application;,,,/Fonts/#FontAwesome</FontFamily>`
определил пару строковых литералов, обозначающих определенные иконки:

```
<system:String x:Key="SearchIcon">&#xf002;</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="SettingsIcon">&#xf110;</system:String>
```

Определил стиль кнопки, которая должна иметь иконку в своем контенте:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="InnerSearchButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
...
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource SearchIcon}"/>
...
</Style>
```

В редакторе все нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот при запуске программы вижу вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема, не подскажете?

Comment: А вы шрифт как подключаете в выполняемый файл?

Comment: что на киберфоруме уже не помогают раз решили сюда перейти?

Comment: Забавно, у меня подобное, но только в обратную сторону всегда. Не как не знаю, как в редакторе убрать квадраты, но не суть... У вас скорей всего просто не находит необходимый ресурс.

Comment: @VladD в плане как? Я же написал как. Добавляю его в ресурс `<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">pack://application;,,,/Fonts/#FontAwesome</FontFamily>` Затем использую в коде. Остальные шрифты таким образом работают

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, Увы, да. На киберфоруме вообще про WPF мало помогают. Ждешь ответа по 3-5 дней. А то и вообще не приходит ответ

Comment: @Bretbas: Нет, вы написали не это. Вы написали, как вы его подключаете. Это не то. Вопрос в том, как вы его включаете в проект.

Comment: Создал Folder для шрифтов в проекте, затем нажал Add -> Add Existing Item и выбрал этот шрифт. Он появился в Folder моих шрифтов проекта. Все

Comment: @Bretbas, правый клик по шрифту в солюшн экплорере, пропертис. Какие настройки там стоят? Это у вас спрашивает VladD.

Comment: @Андрей Да там их не особо много то: Build Action:Resource; Copy to output directory:Do not copy; Custom tool:пусто; Custom tool namespace:пусто; FileName:fontawesome-webfont.ttf; Full path: путь до файла

Comment: Блин, это проблема в чем-то другом, правда я уже весь интернет облазил, и не смог найти информации на эту тему. Как так, что в редакторе VS все нормально отображается, а при выполнении программы нет?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305239/how-use-icon-font-awesome-in-wpf у меня сделано все как здесь

Comment: "Увы, да. На киберфоруме вообще про WPF мало помогают. Ждешь ответа по 3-5 дней. А то и вообще не приходит ответ" может когда-нибудь поймут что блокировка пользователей за их политические убеждения не способствует развитию ресурса.

Comment: @Bretbas закинуть проект на гитхаб или хостинг и дать ссылку не вариант?

Comment: Вроде я нашел ошибку. Очень странно, у меня в файле Font.xaml определялись базовые стили для некоторых контролов; в этих базовый стилях изменялся только шрифт. Все работало, все нормально. Но как только я писал вот так: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>`, то у меня сразу FontAwesome отображался в виде квадратиков при выполнении программы. Очень странная ошибка...

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: А может наоборот, исключают пользователей, которые вместо программирования занимаются политикой, чтобы не создавать на ресурсе ядовитую атмосферу?

Comment: @VladD нет, не может. Даже если бы вы были правы (хотя это очевидно не так) исключение найболее ядовитых пользователей за их политические взгляды все равно развитию ресурса не способствует.